# Angular Bootstrap Toggle prevent default

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I use http://ziscloud.github.io/angular-bootstrap-toggle/

I want in some occasions to display a popup and cancel the toggle action.

```
<toggle ng-click="toggleChanged($event)" style="v3-toggle" ng-model="myModel" on="on" off="" size="btn-xs"></toggle>
```

in my controller

```
$scope.toggleChanged(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

This doesn't work and changes the toggle state instead of prevent it.

Answer (score 0):

try event instead of $event

```
 event.preventDefault();
 event.stopPropagation();
```

Hope this Helps!